# Flutter Firebase dynamic link navigates to correct route on emulator but not on a real android device

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I am creating custom dynamic link as given below:

```
Future<String> generateDynamicLink(
    String pid, String imgurl, String title, String description) async {
  final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
    uriPrefix: uriPrefix,
    link: Uri.parse(
      uriPrefix+'/pd?pid=$pid',
    ),
    androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
      packageName: 'com.test',
      minimumVersion: 0,
    ),
    socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
      description: description,
      imageUrl: Uri.parse(
        imgurl,
      ),
      title: title,
    ),
    dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
      shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable,
    ),
  );

  Uri url = await parameters.buildUrl();
  ShortDynamicLink shortenedLink = await DynamicLinkParameters.shortenUrl(
    url,
    DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
        shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable),
  );
  return shortenedLink.shortUrl.toString();
}
```

And handling the receiving part by calling the **fetchLinkData** (see below) inside the initState of my home page

```
void fetchLinkData(BuildContext context) async {
  var link = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  handleLinkData(link, context);

  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
    onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
      handleLinkData(dynamicLink, context);
    },
    onError: (OnLinkErrorException error) async {
      print(error.message);
    },
  );
}

void handleLinkData(PendingDynamicLinkData data, BuildContext context) async {
  final Uri uri = data?.link;
  if (uri != null) {
    final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
    if (queryParams.keys.contains("pid")) {
      String pid = queryParams["pid"];
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ProductScreen(id: pid),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is, On emulator everything works as expected and when the dynamic link is opened it navigates to the correct page but when I try on my android device only the app is opened.

Comment: Is there any difference how you click link on real device and on emulator?

Comment: No, I copy the link to the clipboard use chrome to open it.

Comment: Try pasting it inside some app like notes or gmail. Once the link appears to be clickable, tap it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Tried whatsapp and gmail, the app opens/foregrounds but still no redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having the same problem, removing the intent filter solved the problem for me.

Comment: what part of the flutter is the intent filter? thanks by the way

Comment: It's in the androidManfest.xml file in android/app/src/main directory. In older versions of FirebaseDynamicLink you had to add an intent filter in the androidmanifest.xml file. You don't have to do that now, just following the docs should work.